# Supremum of Expectation of a Sequence of Random Variables

Tags: integration, probability-theory

Let $(X_1, X_2,...)$ be a sequence of random variables that converges almost surely to a random variable $X$. Show that if $\sup_n EX_n^2 < \infty $, then $EX^2 < \infty$.

I believe this is using either Fatou or Dominated Convergence Theorem, but cannot formulate a complete proof.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fatou's lemma is, I think, the "obvious" way to go. We indeed have 
$$\mathbb E[|X|]=\mathbb E[\liminf_{n\to \infty}|X_n|]\leqslant \liminf_{n\to\infty}\mathbb E[|X_n|]\leqslant \sup_k\mathbb E[|X_k|]\lt \infty.$$