# Show that if $\sup_i \text E(X_i^2) < \infty$, then $\text E(X^2) < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory

**Problem:**

> Let $\{X_i\}_{i = 1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ such that $\lim_{i \to \infty} X_i = X \text{ a.e.}$ Show that if $\sup_i \text E(X_i^2) < \infty$, then $\text E(X^2) < \infty$.

**My Attempt:**

First I want to note that there is an extremely similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591518/supremum-of-expectation-of-a-sequence-of-random-variables) but I don't understand Davide Giraudo's answer. For one thing, his answer doesn't have any $X^2$s in it, which is confusing me.

I will try to explain as best I can. First, I have a version of Fatou's Lemma stating that if $\{X_i\}_{i = 1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of non-negative random variables, then $\text E (\liminf_i X_i) \leq \liminf_i \text E(X_i)$.

If we let $Y_i = X_i^2$ then I have a sequence of non-negative random variables to work with. **One concern of mine is this:** can I assume that $\lim_{i \to \infty} X_i^2 = X^2$? I feel like that's necessary for for what I've written below to work.

If I can make that assumption then we have

\begin{align*}
\text E (X^2) &= \text E(\liminf_i X_i^2) \textbf{ (Is this justified?)}\\
&\leq \liminf_i \text E(X_i^2) \text{ (application of Fatou's Lemma)}\\
&\leq \sup_i \text E(X_i^2) \text{ (property of real numbers)}\\
&< \infty \text{ (by assumption)}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your first step is justified. By the continuous mapping theorem, we have that if $X_n \to X$ almost surely, then $g(X_n) \to g(X)$ almost surely for any continuous function. If we set $g(x) = x^2$, then $$X^2 = \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n^2 = \liminf_{n \to \infty} X_n^2 \quad \text{a.s}$$
where the last equality follows simply because the limit exists. The rest follows by taking expectations and applying Fatou's lemma.